# Black screen on top and bottom of an application in iphone x

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, iphone-x

I have an old application using .xib file and launch image source. whenever I run application on it give me black space on top and bottom. I have added launchscreen @3x in launchscreen images it distort my complete application on iPhonex. i am not using autolayout.Please help me in this issue if anyone get to solve this issue.

Comment: It's hard to help you from the information you have provided. Can you as a minimum post a screenshot of your app running "distorted" on the iPhone X?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are not using launch xib and so you need to added launch image for iPhone-X. of size `1125px × 2436px` for portrait and `2436px × 1125px` for landscape.

If your constraints are set proper app will work as expectation. Else you have to set proper constraints as well